# Light fixture inside knee-wall storage

Tags: electrical, lighting

We framed knee walls in our attic and want to use the areas behind them for storage.  These areas are triangular in cross-section, about 3' high at the knee wall, and of course the ceiling hits the floor at the other end.

What's a safe, cheap way to light these areas?

There's plenty of accessible wiring and framing to secure it to; the question is what kind of lights.  First I bought just regular light sockets with the pull chain that attach to a round ceiling box.  But now I'm worried that bumping into one of these with my head or shoulder will break the bulb off, creating a mess and an electrical hazard.  I heard about a kind of cage that protects the bulb but I can't find anything like that at the big box stores.  Florescent tube lights might be the right shape but probably too much light and cost.  I'm not really interested in battery-powered lights.

What would you do here?

Comment: If you wanted to add a switched outlet, [this](http://www.homedepot.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?storeId=10051&productId=100665727&langId=-1&catalogId=10053&ci_sku=100665727&ci_src=14110944&cm_mmc=shopping-_-googlebase-_-D27X-_-100665727&locStoreNum=804) could work.

Comment: @Doresoom: If it were metal like the old-school ones, I'd go for it.  But not the orange plastic.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the new LED lights would be great for this app.  A little expensive, but will last a long time.  Low temp, low profile and very bright.   Check them out, even at the box stores.

Comment: Nice idea.  I'll check them out.

Answer (score 1):

I grew up with these as a kid and was usually designated to climb to the back to get something out.  Considering how easy it is to fill these spaces up, I think a fixed light is almost always going to be blocked by something (like yourself) when you're searching in a corner, and rendered useless.

Perhaps a rope light that you would find near the Christmas supplies would work, but you may not get enough light out of that.  If it were me, I'd go with a head lamp that I use for camping, but that's battery powered.  Next best option may be a standard cage light on an extension cord so you can move it where you need it.

Answer (score 1):

When I did this in our attic I used the florescent "tube" lights (also known as "linear fluorescent lamps").  I attached them as high as I reasonably could, on the back side of the knee-wall (so they are on the vertical wall instead of the angled rafters.  I installed real light switches near the opening but some fixtures have integrated switches.

I think they work well, come in many sizes, and stay out of the way.

Answer (score 1):

You could use under cabinet floresent lights. They have a cover and unless you hit them pretty hard, you won't break the bulb. They are only an inch think. There are made for hard wiring.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like [this](http://www.northerntool.com/shop/tools/product_200342916_200342916)?

[image: Northern Industrial String Lights — 100ft. String, Metal Lampguards]

A bit on the expensive side (~$130), but it would give you light all over and protect the bulbs.

Or you could go for the classic [Wire Lamp Guard](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=wire%20lamp%20guards&hl=en&prmd=ivns&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=8211094679590751744&sa=X&ei=avTcTcfJLYmWtwfxhai6Dw&ved=0CH8Q8wIwAw&biw=992&bih=593#) for ~$6.

[image]